# Remove all characters of a string after the fourth slash"/"

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I'm looking for a way to remove the fourth slash(/), (and everything following it) from a string ,this function to be for every line list from "input text area"

Example: if i have a list "Vertically" in Input text area(days of the week)

```
Monday/February/8/2016/08:05:07/GMT-0700 (PDT)
Tuesday/February/9/2016/09:07:07/GMT-0700 (PDT)
Wednesday/February/10/2016/01:04:07/GMT-0700 (PDT)
Thursday/February/11/2016/05:15:07/GMT-0700 (PDT)
etc
```

when i click button remove ,results in Output Textarea to be "Vertically" like this:

```
Monday/February/8/2016
Tuesday/February/9/2016
Wednesday/February/10/2016
Thursday/February/11/2016
```

my code:

```
function remove_list() {
  var count = 0;
  var list = document.myForm.Input.value;
  list = list.replace(/^((?:[^ ]* ){3}[^ ]*) [/]*/gm, "$1");

  var listvalues = new Array();
  var newlist = new Array();

  listvalues = list.split(/[\s,]+/).join("");

  var hash = new Object();

  for (var i = 0; i < listvalues.length; i++) {
    if (hash[listvalues[i].toLowerCase()] != 0) {
      newlist = newlist.concat(listvalues[i]);
      hash[listvalues[i].toLowerCase()] = 1
    } else {
      count++;
    }
  }
  document.myForm.Output.value = newlist.join("");

}
```

thank you for your help.

Comment: why do you have spaces in your regex?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`Array#split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split), [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), [`Array#join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) and [`Array#slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) methods and do something like this.

```js
var str = `Monday/February/8/2016/08:05:07/GMT-0700 (PDT)
Tuesday/February/9/2016/09:07:07/GMT-0700 (PDT)
Wednesday/February/10/2016/01:04:07/GMT-0700 (PDT)
Thursday/February/11/2016/05:15:07/GMT-0700 (PDT)`;

console.log(
  // split the string by newline
  str.split('\n')
  // iterate over array
  .map(function(v) {
    // generate the string where removed content after 4th /
    return v.split('/').slice(0, 3).join('/');
    // you can make it much more simpler as in @Mureinik answer
    // return v.split('/', 4).join('/');
    
    // re-join string elements
  }).join('\n')
)
```

---

Or with [`String#replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method.

```js
var str = `Monday/February/8/2016/08:05:07/GMT-0700 (PDT)
Tuesday/February/9/2016/09:07:07/GMT-0700 (PDT)
Wednesday/February/10/2016/01:04:07/GMT-0700 (PDT)
Thursday/February/11/2016/05:15:07/GMT-0700 (PDT)`;

console.log(
  str.replace(/^((?:[^\/]*\/){3}[^\/]*)\/.+$/mg, '$1')
)
```

Comment: yes this String#replace metod work for me, but i have and 1 question how this code: ** str.replace(/^((?:[^\/]*\/){3}[^\/]*)\/.+$/mg, '$1') ** will be if my list is with ** "-" ** :  like this:  ***Tuesday-February-9-2016-09:07:07-GMT-0700 (PDT)
Wednesday-February-10/2016-01:04:07-GMT-0700 (PDT)
Thursday-February-11-201-05:15:07-GMT-0700 (PDT)***

Comment: @MeritaAdemi :  in this case what would be the expected o/p ?

Comment: yes this String#replace metod work for me, but i have and 1 question how this code:`code`str.replace(/^((?:[^\/]*\/){3}[^\/]*)\/.+$/mg, '$1')`code` will be if my list is with  - : like this: ***Tuesday-February-9-2016-09:07:07-GMT-0700 (PDT) Wednesday-February-10-2016-01:04:07-GMT-0700 (PDT) Thursday-February-11-201-05:15:07-GMT-0700 (PDT)***

Comment: otput to be like this Monday-February-8/2016
Tuesday-February-9/2016
Wednesday-February-10-2016
Thursday-February-11-2016

Comment: input: ***Tuesday-February-9-2016-09:07:07-GMT-0700 (PDT) Wednesday-February-10-2016-01:04:07-GMT-0700 (PDT) Thursday-February-11-201-05:15:07-GMT-0700 (PDT)***    output :  ***Monday-February-8-2016
Tuesday-February-9-2016
Wednesday-February-10-2016
Thursday-February-11-2016***

Comment: @MeritaAdemi :  regex need to update `str.replace(/^((?:[^-]*\/){3}[^-]*)-.+$/mg, '$1')`

Comment: your code (/^((?:[^\/]*\/){3}[^\/]*)\/.+$/mg, '$1')  for ***slash/*** working good but for ***hyphen (‐)*** this dosent work   (/^((?:[^-]*\/){3}[^-]*)-.+$/mg, '$1') pleas can you check again for **hyphen (‐)***

Comment: @MeritaAdemi :  just one update  `str.replace(/^((?:[^-]*-){3}[^-]*)-.+$/mg, '$1')`

Comment: thank you so much now its working thank you milion time thanks and to stackoverflow

Answer (score 6):

The easiest would be to just split the string according to the `/` and limit the number of returned elements to four, and the rejoin them:

```
function firstFourFields(s) {
    return s.split('/', 4).join('/');
}
```